# How do I type the Telugu character అ?

Tags: keyboard, language

I am trying to type the telugu character అ on mac, after switching to the Telugu - QWERTY keyboard that ships with mac.

I would think this would show up as an option when holding down the 'a' key, or holding down shift+'a', but only the character ఆ shows up as an option. Is there an easy way to type this character?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just pressing <kbd>option</kbd><kbd>a</kbd> works for me as it produces **అ** (TELUGU LETTER A Unicode: U+0C05, UTF-8: E0 B0 85) not **ఆ** (TELUGU LETTER AA Unicode: U+0C06, UTF-8: E0 B0 86) on a MBP with US Keyboard , when set to Telugu - QWERTY for the keyboard layout.

Pressing <kbd>w</kbd> on the same keyboard produces **అ** also, when set to Telugu - QWERTY for the keyboard layout.

Comment: Although this is obviously a better way, another is to use Unicode Hex Input

Comment: @WGroleau, Since the _keyboard layout_ is already set to Telugu - QWERTY and it works with a key press or two, I fail to see the need to use Unicode Hex Input under the expressed conditions mentioned in the OP and why I didn't even mention it.

Comment: No one suggested it’s a better way.  But it is another way.